Trace32 CMM script : understanding the shift operator
Please check bellow cmm script code, it is throwing error:-
If anyone knows the answer please comment.
&MY_DATA=Data.LONG(ANC:0x300007FF9C8ABC)
&CHECK_VAL=&MY_DATA&(1<<&BITPOS) ;this should work
IF (&CHECK_VAL==(1<<&BITPOS)) ;this should work

error massage was:- IF (&CHECK_VAL==(1<<&BITPOS))
^symbol not found

This code is producing an error - and the exact text of that error message somehow didn't seem like an important detail to include???

error massage was:-
IF (&CHECK_VAL==(1<<BITPOS))
^ symbol not found

Please don't add comments to clarify. Comments don't allow much formatting, and it's not clear what symbol the error refers to. [Edit] your question instead. Make sure your code is a [mcve].

What is BITPOS?
Is it a variable in your target application? Or is it a script macro, like &MY_DATA ?

It is a macro like &MY_DATA.
But my next target is include c header with enum variable as macro in cmm.
I have edited my question please go through once it.

In general your script should work. I assume that your macro &BITPOS does not contain a numeric value.
I suggest debugging your PRACTICE script. To do so:

Open a new PRACTICE editor: Menu > File > New script
Paste your code to the opened PEDIT window. (Ensure that &BITPOS is also defined in that code.)
Click on the button "Debug" in the top of the PEDIT window. The window PLIST opens, in which you can debug your code.
Click on the button "Macro" in the top of the PLIST window, which opens the window PMACRO showing you the values of your script macros/variables while stepping through your script.
Click on the button "Step" in the top of the PLIST window to execute one line after another of your script. Check the content of PMACRO while stepping through your script.

What is the content of &BITPOS right before stepping over the line causing the error?

You assumed that &BITPOS  does not contain a numeric value. But how we can update  &BITPOS if I don't update with numeric value? In my test I have written another file1.cmm script where all  &BITPOS1...2...3 and so on is present and from file2.cmm I am DO file1.cmm and using particular  &BITPOS to check some register's particular bits. In file1.cmm  &BITPOS=96 present. Please let me know how do you expect to update  &BITPOS in file1.cmm?

Another information I would like to give you, I follow your given steps and found that after initialized the macros from file1.cmm it is going clear(not visible in PMACRO window) when script flow comes to file2.cmm, may be that is the reason I am getting this error. Could you please help me how to include file1.cmm into file2.cmm  so that it will remain present as a global macro in file2.cmm file.

Yes , If I do STOre file1.cmm then it is getting memory till file2.cmm end.
STOre file1.cmm
Thanks.

By default, all macros are declared LOCAL, that means that they disappear, when your scirpt ends. If file1.cmm declares the macros for file2.cmm, then please call file2.cmm from file1.cmm before file1.cmm ends. To do so, add the line DO ~~~~/file.cmm to the end of your script file1.cmm (or before ENDDO when your script file1.cmm contains ENDDO).

I have observed all &BITPOS values in file1.cmm files are taken as hex value, is there any way to initialized &BITPOS values as unsigned int value?

Numbers with prefix 0x are hex. Number with suffix . are decimal. Numbers without a 0xin the beginning or a dot at the end are defined by SETUP.RADIX.

I need to assign a integer to a macro.
I have written as    &BITPOS=21   , form PMACRO window I observe  it is taking as 0x21, so when I am trying to shift 1<<&BITPOS  , instead of shifting 21 times left shift of 1 , it is shifting 0x21 times which is 33 in integer value. Note:-  I am not able to found SETUP.RADIX .  reference:- https://repo.lauterbach.com/manual.html  . Almost all documents I opened but not found.

You need to write &BITPOS=21.  instead of &BITPOS=21 (or set SETUP.RADIX Decimal).

FYI: When I enter SETUP.RADIX on https://repo.lauterbach.com/manual.html I get some matches and the first two describe the command pretty well I think.
